# WCF Data Services: Processing an object at save time

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

We are using a WCF Data Service to broker our data server side, and give third parties easy OData access to our data. The server side of things has been relatively easy. The client side, on the other hand, is giving us fits.

We are converting from regular Entity Framework to Data Services, and we've created an assembly which contains the generated client objects that talk to the data service (via a Service Reference). Those classes are partial, so we've added some logic and extended properties to them. This all works great.

The issue we are having is that we need to process our objects at save time, because they need to do some advanced serialization before they are sent over the wire. The DataServiceContext class contains two events: WritingEntity and ReadingEntity. The ReadingEntity event actually happens at the correct time for us (post object deserialization). The WritingEntity event happens at the WRONG time for us (post object serialization).

Is there any way to catch an object before it's written to the request, so that we can call a method on entity that is about to be written?

Obviously we could just loop through the Entities list, looking for any entity that is not in a state of Unchanged or Deleted, and call the appropriate method there...but this would require me to add special code every time I wanted to call SaveChanges on the context. This may be what we need to do, but it would be nice if there was a way to catch the entities before they are written to XML for sending to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no hook in the DataServiceContext to do what you want. The closest I can think of is the approach you suggested with walking all the entities and findings those which were modified. You could do this in your own SaveChanges-like method on the context class (which is also partial).